# why when I am giving a:link color: red; it is not changing it's color?

Tags: html, sass

Sorry my English is not good)
So I was repeating after tutorial and the tutor wrote a:link and gave a property color:red; but when i did so it didn't change it's color
here is html:

```
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="" class="huy">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="huy">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="huy">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="" class="btn-main">Sign up</a>
    <a href="" class="btn-hot">Get a quote</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and SCSS:

```
.navigation{
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  
  li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    
    &:first-child{
      margin: 0;
    }
    a:link{
      color: red;
    }
  }
  
}
```

I wanted a to change it's color

Comment: There are four state of a link - link - normal, visited and hover - on mouse hover, active - click. In your case you might have clicked the link and that changed the state. try updating css like -

`a:link, a:active{ color: red; }`

Comment: Why not style your links on their own?  Do the A, hover, visited, hover all at one time. Keep them separate from the li. That way your CSS is consistant

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To fix the problem put in the `href` a `#` this will navigate to no where but will most likely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put a value in the href. Like:

```
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="..." class="huy">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="..." class="huy">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="..." class="huy">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="..." class="btn-main">Sign up</a>
    <a href="..." class="btn-hot">Get a quote</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rahul Kumar commented, try changing "a:link" to just "a" or "a:active"

```
a{
      color: red;
}
```

Comment: Active is the color when you click the link, not the color of the link. He wants to style the link itself